# How to run web based Postman collection with Newman, on HTTPS protocol

Tags: https, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-newman

I'm trying to run a collection from a free webhosting text files and I can run it easily with:

```
newman run %https://mysite.txt%
```

Now I'm trying to locally capture the sent requests from the newman run so I'm adding this command in CMD:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:62248
```

this should allow my app to record requests from Newman when using it like that:

```
newman run %https://mysite.txt% --env-var HTTP_PROXY --insecure
```

(it works perfect on local hosted files)
However since the txt file is hosted by https protocol, I'm getting the following error:

```
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to fetch data from url "https://mysite.txt"
  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 62248
```

Can I run Newman collection from a secure https web address while locally recording it, or should I download and save it first locally and then run it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current temporary(hopefully I'll get a better one), is to download the file from wherever it's being stored, and run Newman locally with the downloaded file.